# PHP Strings to hashmap

Tags: php, string, algorithm, hash, modulus

Given a array of 6 unique strings (which I don't know in advance and are always given in a ramdom order) how can I map these strings so that each string can be assigned a number from 1-6 (or 0-5). And be assigned the same number on the next script run?

I should also add that not all strings are passed every script run

e.g.

```
// Script Run 1: 
string1 => 2
string2 => 6
string3 => 5
string6 => 1


// Script Run 2: 
string3 => 5
string4 => 4
string2 => 6
string5 => 3

// Note how strings 2 and 3 have the same mapping
```

I assume something along the lines of hashing and mod(6), but not sure how to implement. Any suggestions?

**Note: this is in a script and sessions not availble**

Thanks in advance

Comment: are these `strings` same every time , i mean do `string6` or `string5` has same value on every load?

Comment: Why not just save the array in a session and use the index as the # on the next page load?  Otherwise, I'm not sure what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: sessions are available in this instance - Page loads maybe a bad example - I will update question

Comment: With the updated question, I have a new question. ^^ What method(s) do you have available to store content between the two script runs?  It may be that I am still not understanding the question, but if the strings are random each run and you have no control over them - there needs to be a way to save state between each time the script runs.

Comment: This is why I am asking how to guarantee that a certain string will always map to a certain number - hence the modulus 6 part of my question

Comment: Ok, with that clarification I understand the question, but the question itself doesn't seem to make it clear that no storage at all is available - at least to me. ^^  That being said, if the set isn't available in full each time, you won't have a way to do collision testing if two end up the same (ie, when using modulus).  This presents a problem with a dataset that starts at 6, you assign numbers based on a hash/modulus combo with collision detection, and then the next time, you have 3, but one of those is no longer colliding and won't be re-assigned correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Examples of Modulus Usage for Assigning Numbers

With the requirement that each string be limited to a number between 0 and 5, or 1 and 6, with a changing/incomplete data-set, it will be impossible to achieve the desired end-result.  Say we take 6 strings, we'll crc them, and then do modulus 6 and display the results.  The input:

```
Array
(
    [0] => string1
    [1] => string2
    [2] => string3
    [3] => string4
    [4] => string5
    [5] => string6
)
```

The `crc32` (using `sprintf('%u', crc32('string'))`:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 742935113
    [1] => 3040943091
    [2] => 3259378533
    [3] => 1545780934
    [4] => 723881552
    [5] => 2989285354
)
```

The results of `crc32 % 6`:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 5
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 1
    [3] => 4
    [4] => 2
    [5] => 1
)
```

As you can see, 'string2', 'string3', and 'string6' all had collisions with the [bucket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#bucket) that would result in them being assigned a '1', with collision detection, a simple `+1` until finding an empty bucket will be used for this example.   So we'd end up with our `bucket` array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => string6
    [1] => string2
    [2] => string3
    [3] => string5
    [4] => string4
    [5] => string1
)
```

The next time around, suppose we get rid of `[1] => string2` from the original input, then our array of 6 results would look like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 
    [1] => string3
    [2] => string5
    [3] => string6
    [4] => string4
    [5] => string1
)
```

This shows what happens when the data-set is incomplete with a small number of keys, the numbers assigned are drastically different for some.

The problem is the `load`.  The Load of this is 100%, as there are 6 possible texts, and only 6 `buckets`.  When creating a hash table, you want the load to be approaching 0, and for a 50% load with 6 entries, you'd need 12 buckets available.

**Keep in mind**

While using a `modulus` in PHP, you also have to keep in mind the maximum integer size, [as any value used for the modulus operation will be cast in to an integer](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php):

> Operands of modulus are converted to integers (by stripping the decimal part) before processing.

Depending on your system, that is either going to be a 32bit or 64bit one.  An unsigned crc32 will exceed the maximum cap on a 32bit system and return the int cap, which means that half the numbers will end in the same bucket (statistically), which is exactly what happened when half our values previously ended up in bucket '1'.

### What Can We Do?

Well, the problem is the range of numbers that we have available to choose from.  Depending on the desired application for assigning different strings numbers, we can use the real `crc32` as the number of collisions from the results would be minimal for a small data-set - however if we need a sequential set of numbers for the input text (or within a small range as described), there is no solution that would allow for a partial data-set, while keeping the assigned numbers constant through each run. With the input strings being random in order each time the script is run, there is absolutely no way to keep resulting integer the same each time as the collisions may inverse their order if they are processed at different times between each run.

If the purpose is to label a file, or a means of access to something, use a larger hash, and don't `mod` it to fit it down to size.